# Slideshow autostart (with toggle)

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

http://jsfiddle.net/r6uf38v4/

So. Once the page has been loaded, i want the slider to automatically start. But with the checkbox to be an option to pause it (then resume)

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
```

How do I make it start automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starting your slider automatically you just have to call:
`$('#checkbox').trigger('change');`
This triggers the change event and starts the slider.

For pausing and resuming you could use something like this:

```
var moveInterval;


$('#checkbox').change(function () {
    if (!moveInterval) {
        moveInterval = setInterval(function () {
            moveRight();
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(moveInterval);
        moveInterval = false;
    }
});
```

Everytime the change event is fired check if the `moveInterval` is defined. If it's not, define it. If it is, clear it and set it to false.

Updated your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r6uf38v4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
  if(!$(this).prop('checked')){
      moveRight();
$(this).data('slideshow', setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 3000));
  } else {
      clearInterval($(this).data('slideshow'));
  }
});
```

First it will check if the checkbox is not checked. If it's not checked, then start by calling moveRight and then starting up the interval. Store it in the element so next time it's clicked (it will be checked) you can clear it out, stopping the slideshow.

The fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/r6uf38v4/2/

**EDIT**: I just realized you also wanted to make it start at the beginning.

Lets modify it a bit so it will only initially moveRight when clicking it:

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function(ev, load){
  var load = load === undefined ? false : true;
  if(!$(this).prop('checked')){
      if(!load) { moveRight(); }
$(this).data('slideshow', setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 3000));
  } else {
      clearInterval($(this).data('slideshow'));
  }
});
```

I added an extra argument so if it's loading, it will not moveRight initially. Then you just have to trigger the function:

```
$('#checkbox').trigger('change', {load : true});
```

Also, lets get "checked" out of the html, otherwise it will not start the interval but clear it (since it's checked).

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
```

New Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/r6uf38v4/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could have the animation in a separate function that gets called with $(document).ready(). Then the checkbox function could just control the logic to start and stop the animation depending on the checked state.